# tangent vectors

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $S$ be any regular surface in $R^3$ and let $p \in S$ be any point. 
From Classical differential Geometry I Know that the tangent space of $S$ at p is a subspace of $R^3$.

If I see the surface as a manifold then I have the description of the tangent space via the derivations.

How can pass from one to another?

Comment: Have you read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_space#Definition_via_derivations ?